# Invalid Argument Types for UDF Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Trying to resolve the invalid argument types for udf error. A simple example shown below

```
create or replace function udtf_fun15(x numeric(5,2), y numeric(5,2))
returns table(Result numeric(11,2))
language SQL
as 
$$
    select X + Y
    union
    select X - Y
    union
    select X * Y
    union
    select X / Y
    union
    select X % Y
    
$$;
```

//executed successfully

```
select * from table(udtf_fun11(32.4,1.8))
```

// throws the error

> "SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 20 Invalid argument types for function 'UDTF_FUN11': (NUMBER(3,1), NUMBER(2,1))"

I tried the above code and it throws the folowing error,
SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 20 Invalid argument types for function 'UDTF_FUN11': `(NUMBER(3,1), NUMBER(2,1))`

Comment: try only `number`  for the function or use conversion to numeric https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_decimal

Answer (score 0):

Providing explicit argument data types:

```
select * from table(udtf_fun15(32.4::NUMERIC(5,2), 1.8::NUMERIC(5,2)));
```

Output:

```
RESULT
34.2
30.6
58.32
18
0
```